# Start a new Activity without Disrupting Current Activity in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-activity, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Main Activity which displays a View which is Transparent, below is the code (**Trying something like Snackbar which does not disrput the activity**)

```
 [Activity(Label = "MainActivity", Theme = 
  "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Transparent.NoActionBar", MainLauncher =true)]
public class MainActivity: Activity
{
    //Transparent View
    TestView testView;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        testView = new TestView(this);
        SetContentView(testView);

    }
}
```

I Want the activity not to Disrupt the current Activity

**For Example:**
I have a youtube video playing

[image]

I want the video to be played while I start my App activity, but that doesn't happen and it stops the video

[image]

how to achieve it? should I use Threads? but how?

Comment: When you open an `Activity`, the previous `Activity` will execute `onStop()` method, stop video will be a normal behavior, why do you need to continue playing it?

Comment: I want to do something on the current activity without stopping the previous activity, so I can still watch the video and do something on current activity.

Comment: @VINNUSAURUS I think for what you want to do you need to review fragments https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/fragments/

Comment: You may be able to do what you want by just adding `View`s to the existing `Activity`. If you transition to a new `Activity` this will definitely cause some interruption.